# What is the difference between ipfs.add and ipfs.dag.put?

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

Using the `js-ipfs` lib, I'm struggling to find good information regarding the difference between the following commands:

```
> await ipfs.add('hello world',{cidVersion:1})
{
  path: 'bafkreifzjut3te2nhyekklss27nh3k72ysco7y32koao5eei66wof36n5e',
  cid: CID(bafkreifzjut3te2nhyekklss27nh3k72ysco7y32koao5eei66wof36n5e),
  size: 11,
  mode: undefined,
  mtime: undefined
}
> await ipfs.dag.put('hello world')
CID(bafyreifg3qptriirganaf6ggmbdhclgzz7gncundvtsyrovyzqigm25jfe)
```

My expectation: CIDs would be the same.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Below is based on `ipfs add` and `dag put` from [Kubo RPC](https://docs.ipfs.tech/reference/kubo/rpc/), but JS-IPFS was based on it and most likely does something similar (only difference may be that `dag put` in Kubo expects/requires dag-json by default)

- `ipfs add` is for adding files and directories and representing them as [UnixFS](https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/file-systems/#unix-file-system-unixfs). It will chunk bigger files into smaller blocks and represent them as [dag-pb](https://ipld.io/specs/codecs/dag-pb/spec/) or raw bytes (leaves).
- `ipfs dag put` allows you to operate on [IPLD](https://ipld.io/) data structures other than files and directories. In Kubo, this command  will assume input to be [dag-json](https://ipld.io/specs/codecs/dag-json/spec/) and will store it as binary [dag-cbor](https://ipld.io/specs/codecs/dag-cbor/spec/).

You can compare produced CIDs at https://cid.ipfs.tech – in your example:

- `ipfs add` created raw block (because 'hello world' fits in a single block, no need for dag-pb)
- `ipfs dag` created dag-cbor (because that is the default `--store-codec`)